# Want to create a circular list in android

Tags: android, list, mobile, circular-list

I have been facing a small problem from past 3 days. My task is to design a screen with two fragments.(Left side, and right side)

Leftside fragment will contain a list, but this list will appear in circular view , means for example

|@
|->@

|--->@

|----->@

|------>@

|------->@

|------->@

|------->@

|------>@

|----->@

|---->@

|-->@

|@

and it should be rotatable,when i rotate the list , i have to display the data corresponding the list item that is at center in the second (Right side) fragment. I am planning to use fragments.

Can any one help me to solve the issue

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion:

You can work with ListView and then draw all the child views by yourself.

Ok here is how you can do:

Create your own ListView by creating a new class and derive that class from ListView class.
Then if it is needed you can remove the separators by using this method setDivider(Drawable divider) 
Then you will have to use the drawChild(Canvas canvas, View child, long drawingTime) 
Also you might end up using this method as well protected void dispatchDraw (Canvas canvas) ///will need to be overriden in your new ListView class to gain more control

If the circular list will only have strings in it then you will have to start truncating strings starting from the middle index of the list items....Producing a circular motion affect.

Here I am considering that the ListView class will call the drawChild method each time there is a movement on the list and there we can produce slight animation

Let me know how you get on with it...

Answer (score 1):

If you will be using a custom adapter then in your bindview method..grab each childview and give the view a new margin layout parameter with a multiplier that is incrementing and decrementing according to total child views present.

you can get total childs displayed by getCount();

Apply the margin layout to the viewgroup.

I've done the same things except my structure corresponds to a ladder like pattern.

EDIT:
These are some broken snippets from my code to get you an idea.

```
//This is my custom adapter that extends CursorAdapter
 @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) 
{
final RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.text_wrapper);
//This is a parent view that i assigned as a top parent in my xml defining rows of listview
I am finding it through view of bindview. If i don't do this I'll get NPE.

//this is how you will be setting margins for each view

ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) parent
                .getLayoutParams();
//here I am getting my relative layouts margin params.
mlp.leftMargin = 50*multiplier; //this will offset your each row. here multiplier can be like 0,1,2,3,2,1,0 giving you a circular view.you might have to write some method to get your desired multiplier value.
```

The bind view gets called each time the NotifyDatasetChanged is called and gets called for each row that is visible on screen.Hence you can get a circular patter for rows that are visible.

}

Comment: Thanks for the response,
can you send me the code to brsudheerbr@gmail.com

Comment: sorry I can't send you the code as it won't be helpful for anyone else. Plus I can't give you a code here itself as my background implementation is completely different from what your project might be. The broken snippets that I gave you are for giving you an idea how you will achieve your own implementation. Let me know If I can be more helpful.